# d3.js Bitcoin chart shape is wrong

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bitcoin

[image]

Why Is my d3.js chart scale different from http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/bitstampUSD

I have only replaced the data from [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) example and removed the axis (mine is the blue line)

The bitstamp chart has a different look to its shape, how is this done in d3?? What are they doing?

theirs is travelling horizontally downward, mine is just horizontal in direction.

linear isn't it because my blue line is linear, I can't find anything on logarithmic I tried in d3 and my chart turned to a vertical-up-and-down scribble

What are they doing, this is driving me crazy for 2 weeks now

Comment: honestly looks like there are way more entries in your line than the other one, so maybe the first one is a smaller interval of data?

Comment: Are they using some sort of average to smooth out the graph?

Comment: Looks like the y axis in theirs is longer and x is shorter. And results seem intuitive?

Comment: I might be onto something good with the y scale as pow().exponent(-13) it looks alot closer to the bitstamp one

Answer (score 0):

The bitstamp chart is the daily price while your data appears to be an n-hourly data set.

You would need to post a sample of your data for a better answer to the question.